# Best practices for generating wiring diagrams

Tags: schematics, wiring

I started a new job a few months ago with a company that designs heavy machinery used in construction (excavators, backhoes, etc.).

I am finding their wiring diagrams (they call them schematics) are extremely messy, and it is hard to find what you are looking for without having to flip through each and every page.

I am looking for some best practices from someone with experience in this industry on what I should include on a wiring diagram.

Are there any good examples that someone has that I can review?

Some other questions I have:

1. Are harnesses usually shown on a wiring diagram?
2. are connectors usually shown?
3. How should the wiring diagram be laid out?

Thanks.

Comment: We have [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics) targeted more to schematics, but it may be a good start.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We literally draw our harnesses, in full color, in a CAD program.   Complete with accurate representations of each connector.   The results are clear as day to anybody who needs to reference one.   Which is really what the drawings are for... telling a clear story to a reader.  Messy diagrams drive me nuts and I'll call people out on 'em when I find 'em.

Comment: Should try matching a Citroen wiring diagram to a car from about 1990 or so. All the wires were black with little numbers stamped at the ends in white, did not last long in the engine compartment. But if you could hold the diagram in your head you were ok.

Comment: Then you could ask all the manufacturers to use the same colours for the same purpose… Take care as brown for some cars is unfused battery positive while on other cars it is the ground…

Answer (score 1):

I think good practices are to

- display all components, (even connectors, unconnected pins, unused
  logical gates from an IC for example etc...)
- if needed, display a function as a diagram-block style if you don't know yet the solution for it
- avoid crossing wires
- put all inputs on left
- put all outputs on right
- always put positive voltage in high direction
- always put negative voltage & ground in down direction
- separate sub-diagrams by functions
  *(power/input/compare/amplification/logic/outputs)* and so on
- add enough & pertinent comments *(functions/optional or not etc...)*
- display values of components with their tolerance when already known

This should be the real minimum.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that harnesses and connectors are usually included, but not on the same page as any circuitry -- Usually on their own page.

Most often, labels are placed on each pin, and the labels are used on all the other pages.

Comment: It's a pain, and seems like lost work, but having a cad drawing for each harness is the way to go. Numbering _every_ wire with a unique number helps.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on if you need the diagram to indicate where the wires go or if you need to indicate how to manufacture them for contractors or internally.

A system block diagram can indicate where the wires go from board to board or device to device ect.

A manufacturing diagram should indicate how to construct the cable. It needs to indicate part numbers for pins, connectors and shells, and clearly mark where the wires/pins go.

Some ideas:

- Generate either diagram in your favorite block diagram program (mine is visio)
- Mark pins (by number) at least mark pin 1.
- Mark what the connector is (usually with a part number for shell)
- Indicate wire size and if the wires are twisted or shielded
- Wire lengths and colors
- Wire material
- Where the wires go (like to a designator on a PCB)